# From crystal reports cstr format to ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, expression

I got this crystal formula that I need to make into an ssrs expression:

```
cstr(val({?@Year}) - 1,"000#")
```

Which format is `"000#"` and what is it equal to in SSRS?

Can't I just as well have `=CStr(Parameters!Year.Value - 1)`. Cause what in this case does `val` and `"000#"` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that format string would have just formatted it with no commas or decimals. In SSRS, this would be the default behavior, so no need to even add formatting specifications. If the Year parameter is a number, you can simply do `=Parameters!Year.Value - 1`.